# Ruby on Rails sorting hash of hashes based on value of child hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, hash

I have looked at many other ruby hash/sorting posts but just can't seem to get this one down. I have I have a 'payrolls' hash, built from looping through an ActiveRecord set of completed work over a given date period. There are datepickers to select the to and from dates and I would like to order the output by users with most hours worked.

```
schedules = Schedule.where(:employer => employer_id).includes(:employee).order('date ASC')
@payrolls = Hash.new()

schedules.each do |p|   
    payrolls[p.employee.first_name] ||= {}
    payrolls[p.employee.first_name]['money_earned'] = payrolls[p.employee.first_name]['money_earned'].to_f + p.money_earned.to_f
    payrolls[p.employee.first_name]['hours_worked'] = payrolls[p.employee.first_name]['hours_worked'].to_f + p.hours_worked.to_f
end

@payrolls.sort_by { |k, v| v[:money_earned] }
```

I know this is maybe a bit PHP like for building the hash but it's my first major rails project after 5 years of PHP development. As long as it works it's OK but I wouldn't say no to a better alternative!

And my view, purely for testing the moment:

```
<%  @payrolls.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="payroll_employee">
        <%= key %> <%= value['money_earned'] %> <%= value['hours_worked'] %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The sorting just doesn't have any effect at all currently, no matter what I change it to it outputs in the same order and I'm starting to think I am missing a major (and probably obvious) part of hashes in Ruby. Thanks for any and all suggestions.

Edit for output:
    (id, name, hours, earned)

```
1 | Tom Jones | 10.51 | 105.1
3 | Peter Griffen | 7.5 | 75.0
2 | Joseph Rogers | 6.2 | 62.0
4 | Weee Joss | 14.0 | 140.0
```

Comment: Here's one problem with the code as written. You initialize `payrolls[p.employee.first_name]` and then immediately check whether it's `nil`. But it can't be `nil` after it's just been initialized. So the first block of your conditional will never be executed. I don't think that's your main problem, however - not sure about that yet.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks. I think the fact even the answer you have below isn't sorting it there may be a more fundamental problem with my hash rather than a sorting issue?

Comment: You were right (of course), getting rid of that whole conditional to check for nil the behavior is the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. `Enumerable#sort_by` does not modify in place. You need to reassign the return value to `@payrolls`.
2. You're constructing a `Hash`, not a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. Since you're using string keys, you need to be consistent about that. Your `#sort_by` sorts by a symbol key.

Try this:

`@payrolls = @payrolls.sort_by { |_, v| v['money_earned'] }`

Just to add some more information:

The return value of this expression is actually not even a `Hash`. Here's an example:

```
1.9.3p392 :012 > { a: { q: 1 }, c: { q: 3 }, b: { q: 2 } }.sort_by { |_, v| v[:q] }
 => [[:a, {:q=>1}], [:b, {:q=>2}], [:c, {:q=>3}]]
```

The cool part is that your view code will work anyway with no modification, even if it gets an array of arrays!

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Sadly I still get the same output, output is the following:

    (id | name | hours | earned)

    1 | Tom Jones | 10.51 | 105.1 
    3 | Peter Griffen | 7.5 | 75.0
    2 | Joseph Rogers | 6.2 | 62.0
    4 | Weee Joss | 14.0 | 140.0

Do I need something else as they are floating point values?

Comment: Sorry about formatting. Have added this an edit to my original post

Comment: Awesome that worked! My poor approach to the hash creation certainly wasn't helping. Only thing now is it sorts from low to high rather than high to low but I should be able to find the answer to that one. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Yup last bit was nice and easy, just added .reverse. Thanks again.